# how to fix a corrupted rds licenses database?

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-services, rds

***The problem***

A license database for remote desktop in Windows 2012 got corrupted as helpdesk executes several times an script in powershell used to install licenses for Windows 2008 R2 and then for Windows 2012

***The troubleshooting***

Reviewing the licenses installed on the system, several entries were found some for Windows 2012 and others for Windows 2008.

We tried the following procedures in order to delete the licenses:

[Removing and adding back the RDS role](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755232.aspx) - nothing happened, as soon as the role was installed, the same corrupted database emerged

[Rebuilding database](http://www.vkernel.ro/blog/how-to-remove-rds-cals-from-a-rd-license-server) - we tried all options... nothing happened

[Executing some PS commands](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7ced888b-30ad-42cb-af9b-816ff252f383/uninstall-ts-device-cals-windows-2008-standard-edition) - nothing happened

[More googling... basically the same commands as in the previous link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/381c3bb2-427c-4179-b668-964a2f377c3f/remove-rds-2012-cals-from-the-license-server?forum=winserverTS) - nothing happened

Comment: Sounds like a ServerFault question to me. I have a fix documented for the rds 120 grace period somewhere that may help with this problem but don't remember as it's been a while. Let me know if interested and will dig for it if so.

Answer (score 0):

***The answer***

After several spent time we were able to recreate the database doing the following:

1.- Remove the RDS role

2.- Delete or rename the folder C:\Windows\System32\LServer (this is where the database file lives)

3.- Install the RDS role - the LServer folder will be created from the scratch so no license will be there

Extra

4.- Just in case, enable the feature [RD Connection Broker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725560.aspx) if the server is intended for supporting several connections

I hope this helps anyone out there